# Can not pass string in setAttribute

Tags: c++, tinyxml

```
TiXmlElement * book = new TiXmlElement( "book" );  
    root->LinkEndChild( book );  
    string str1="name";
    const string str2=catalog[i].id();
    book->SetAttribute(str1,str2);
```

i get errors like
[Error] no matching function for call to 'TiXmlElement::SetAttribute(std::string&, const string&)'

i need to set the attribute anyhow.

Comment: Any reason you're not doing `TiXmlElement book("book");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you forget to `#define TIXML_USE_STL`?

Comment: Seriously Casey it helped me a lot. Am a noob and i missed it totally. thanx problem is solved by giving 

#define TIXML_USE_STL in the beginning of tinixml.h